# Pointing out the changes in direction within a list Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, dataset

I am trying to run a code where it runs through a list and when it changes directions it will `print(direction changed)`. When the `List_` is on an upside until the `(7,153054.54)` value from the `(6,198913.81)`, realize how the value went down to 153054.54 from 198913.81 the program must print `print(direction changed)`.

```
list_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
List_ = [100.00, 9313.38, 43601.28, 61701.69, 74331.88, 198913.81, 153054.54, 119162.10, 74382.25, 203542.82, 160774.71, 220307.19, 366459.26]
Outputs = [print('upside change') if a < b else print(downside change) for a,b in zip(L_Amount_list,L_Amount_list[1:])]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? SO will help you with your issues but SO is not a coding service. Show us your attempt.

Comment: I have updated it @DuDa

Comment: I think you have to present your effort/research to find the problem, not just throw out the question and ask for help.  Please read the `how to ask question` section.

Answer (score 0):

@firefireeyyy -based on your sample input, here is the solution you're looking for.  Change the `List_` variable name to `L` here.  However, it's not clear what if the two consecutive numbers are `equal`?

```py
for i in range(1, len(L)):
    if L[i] > L[i-1]:
        print('upside change')
    else:
        print('downside change')
```